# Where do I find the settings for adding a vocabulary to a content type in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

In Drupal 7, I can't find the ***Content types and Required*** setting under ***edit vocabulary***.

How do I customise it?

***Drupal6***

[image]

***Drupal7***

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Head over to the **Manage fields** tab of your content type. For example, for "article" that would be admin/structure/types/manage/article/fields. Then add a **Term Reference** field.

This question is about Drupal 7, but be aware that *Term Reference* appears to be deprecated and potentially be removed from Drupal 8 (in favor of the entity reference field). For more details on that, refer to the question about "[Are there any benefits/caveats with using Entity Reference over Term Reference?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54830)", in which there is a comment also like "*Term reference isn't going anywhere and there will be an upgrade path from 7 to 8*".

Comment: The term reference field is not a good option. It has been deprecated and removed from Drupal 8 in favour of the entity reference field. Using term reference will lead to problems if and when the site will be migrated to Drupal 8. Entity reference is the way!

Comment: Is there no upgrade path for D7 term reference to D8 entity reference? I would imagine there is, since this is quite a common thing. And there is some useful logic in D7 that is only available for term reference, afaik. So it can still be preferable to use that.

Comment: See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54830/are-there-any-benefits-caveats-with-using-entity-reference-over-term-reference and https://www.drupal.org/node/1681908

Comment: @donquixote : interesting comment / question, I would hope such upgrade path is (or will be) available too ...